# Javascript - regex doesn't work on MAC OS - encoding?

Tags: reactjs, regex

I have the following situation:

On my React app I have this regex to validate file names:

```
const validCharsRegex = /^([\w\s()+[żźćńółęąśŻŹĆĄŚĘŁÓŃ-]+)(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)?$/;

if (!validCharsRegex.test(file.name)) {
    errorLabels.push(translate(labels.forbiddenCharacters));
}
```

I want to allow using polish chars in file names.

The problem occurs only for file names on *Mac OS X* system like `różowożółty.pdf`. I have some open component rc-upload that takes file name and processes it further.

On *Windows* all file names like `różowo-żółty.pdf` are matched, so it's OK. But no match for file with the same name created on *Mac OS X* laptop. How can I solve the problem? Probably with encoding???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because **accented chars are stored differently on *Mac OS X*
and *Windows***.

*Windows* uses UTF-16 for file names, so most codepoints are encoded
in 2 bytes. Outside the basic multilingual plane, they are encoded in
a "surrogate pair", which will occupy 4 bytes. This means that you can
have a file such as `écosse.pdf` where `é` could be stored in one
single codepoint or in two codepoints, where `e` would be followed
by a Unicode acute accent `´`. This means that your folder could
store twice a file called `écosse.pdf` (once with `é` and once with
`e` + `´`), which can be very confusing!

On *Mac OS X*, they use UTF-8 but with Unicode **NFD**
(**N**ormalization **F**orm Canonical **D**ecomposition).
This means that `é` will always be stored with 2 codepoints:
`e` + `´`. This avoids having several files with the same name.

In *JavaScript*, you can normalize a string with the
`.normalize()` method :

```js
const filenames = [
  'ecosse.pdf', // No accent at all
  'écosse.pdf', // 1 codepoint to store "é"
  'écosse.pdf'  // 2 codepoints to store "é" = "e" + "´"
];

filenames.forEach(filename => {
  // You can separate the letter and the accent codepoints with
  // the help of .normalize('NFD');
  const nfdFilename = filename.normalize('NFD');
  console.log({
    original: {
      string: filename,
      length: filename.length
    },
    NFD: {
      string: nfdFilename,
      length: nfdFilename.length
    }
  });
});
```

In order to validate your pattern, you'll have to choose between
NFD or NFC. This example explains your problem :

```js
const filenames = [
  'różowo-żółty.pdf', // NFC (Most probably Windows)
  'różowo-żółty.pdf', // NFD (Mac OS X)
  'różowo-żółty.pdf', // mix of NFC and NFD (possible on Windows but not Mac OS X).
];

filenames.forEach(filename => {
  const nfdFilename = filename.normalize('NFD');
  const nfcFilename = filename.normalize('NFC');
  console.log({
    original: {
      string: filename,
      length: filename.length
    },
    NFD: {
      string: nfdFilename,
      length: nfdFilename.length
    },
    NFC: {
      string: nfcFilename,
      length: nfcFilename.length
    }
  });
});
```

By the way, with *JavaScript*, you can use the **u** pattern modifier
or the **v** pattern modifier to enable Unicode handling. This will
offer you the possibility to use `\p{L}` to match any letter in any
language. You can be more specific with `\p{Latin}`, but this might
still not be exactly what you want as polish characters seem to be
another character class. But **if you convert the string
to NFC then you can use your pattern** :

```js
const regexFilename = /^([\w\s()+[żźćńółęąśŻŹĆĄŚĘŁÓŃ-]+)(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)?$/;

const filenames = [
  'różowo-żółty.pdf', // NFC (Most probably Windows)
  'różowo-żółty.pdf', // NFD (Mac OS X)
  'różowo-żółty.pdf', // mix of NFC and NFD (possible on Windows but not Mac OS X).
];

filenames.forEach(filename => {
  console.log({
    filename: filename,
    match: filename.normalize('NFC').match(regexFilename)
  });
});
```

Comment: WORKS! The last approach works!